# laravel vue import plugins [vue-chat-scroll]

Tags: plugins, vue.js, laravel-5.4, vue-directives

I'm relatively new to Vue.js and now I want to install this plugin [vue-chat-scroll](https://github.com/theomessin/vue-chat-scroll) with in my Laravel application, but it throws this error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: chat-scroll
>
> (found in [ChatLog])

I ran `npm install --save vue-chat-scroll` successful.
My `package.json` has the enty for the plugin:

```
"dependencies": {    
    "laravel-echo": "^1.3.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-chat-scroll": "^1.1.1"
}
```

In `bootstrap.js` I added the 2 lines as described in the readme.

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueChatScroll from 'vue-chat-scroll'
Vue.use(VueChatScroll);


window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

In my `ChatLog.vue` I added the `v-chat-scroll` directive.

```
<template lang="html">
<div class="chat-log" v-chat-scroll>
    <chat-message v-for="message in messages" :message="message"></chat-message>
</div>
</template>

<script >
export default{
    props: ['messages']

}
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you recompile your assets after referencing the package in `bootstrap.js`? Also you might want to try `require('vue-chat-scroll')` instead of your `import` (ES5 approach in docs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a single file components you have to define the requirements inside the components themselves.

try this:

```
<script >
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueChatScroll from 'vue-chat-scroll'
Vue.use(VueChatScroll)

export default{
    props: ['messages']
}
</script>
```

It's annoying but thankfully webpack will optimize away the dual requires, or if this the only place you need it you can remove it from bootstrap.js